# Webapp seems to be getting redirected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, apache

I am working on a webapp for a school project that uses JQuery, along with some of my own JS code. There seems to be a strange tendancy across the site for the browser (regardless of if I use firefox or chrome) to be redirected back to the main page (index.html).

For example, I have a page called create.html which includes JQuery and has a button defined as follows:

```
<button onclick="addEmail()"type="create" class="button button-block"/>+</button>
```

the addEmail function does not include any code to redirect or otherwise change the page. Even when the onclick attribute is removed entirely the browser ends up back on the index.html page once the button is clicked. The index.html page also does not render correctly when it is loaded in this manner. We have the following includes in the create.html file:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/create.js"></script>
```

The files are hosted on an apache server as well.

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: _"also does not render correctly..."_ in what way? That's a pretty good clue to what is going on.

Comment: If you use button tag within a form, then it acts like submit type and calls the form action on click. If this is the issue, use input tag with type='button' attribute.

Comment: @coderMe the index page has 2 tabs, one for creating an account and one for logging in. If I understand correctly JQuery handles those (the other guy in my group wrote it). When it gets redirected there unintentionally, there are no tabs and the elements are all sort of dumped out onto the page. Chrome also gives a warning:
"Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/."
From jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5

Comment: @Rajashekhar that seems to have fixed the problem, thank you very much!